# How to replace first half of string in a text file

Tags: php, file, str-replace

I have a text file that has data and is separated by a delimiter of commas. An example of this text file is like `User,data,date` the value of date is set of when the data was entered. If I wanted to remove this line of data, is it possible to do an `str_replace` of just `User,data` and then get it to be replaced with nothing. I'm not too familiar with how `str_replace` works when it comes to replacing certain lines aside from if it's the exact value.

example of what i am asking.

Text file: `Austin,12,1:23:08pm`

Code:

```
$content = file_get_contents('');
str_replace("Austin,12","",$content);
file_put_contents('');
```

So instead of getting all the data in the line, I exclude the last line of it. 
If more explanation is needed, I will edit post. Thanks!

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php and then just write back index 2.

Comment: this isn't a csv though because csv has more file size than a text file so I decided not to go with it. I've done the math with file sizes between the two

Comment: `CSV == Comma Seperated Value`  **Its a text file of any size** And this file contains lines that are errr comma seperated :)

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming you create a text file named "file" then on it you have a text "Austin,12,1:23:08pm". The following code should work for you.

```
//read the text file
$textfile_data='';
$textfile_name='file.txt';
$fh = fopen("$textfile_name",'r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  //append the text file content into textfile_data variable
  $textfile_data.= $line;
}
fclose($fh);

//now textfile_data variable has the text file text
$text_to_replace='Austin,12';
//replace the text you want
$new_textfile_data=str_replace("$text_to_replace",'',$textfile_data);


//write the text file
$fp = fopen("$textfile_name", 'w');
if(fwrite($fp, "$new_textfile_data")){
    echo 'Replaced successfully';
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usiing `fgetcsv()` and assuming an input file like this

tst.dat (A csv file)

```
Austin,12,1:23:08pm
Smith,13,2:23:08pm
Jones,14,3:23:08pm
```

And code like this

```
<?php
if (($input = fopen("tst.dat", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    if (($output = fopen("new.dat", "w")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($line = fgetcsv($input, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            //echo $line[0] . ', ' . $line[1] . ', ' . $line[2] . PHP_EOL;
            fwrite($output, $line[2] . PHP_EOL);
        }
        fclose($output);
    }
    fclose($input);
}
```

You would get an output file called `new.dat` like this

```
1:23:08pm
2:23:08pm
3:23:08pm
```

And to effect only a specific line in the file

```
<?php
if (($input = fopen("tst.dat", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    if (($output = fopen("new.dat", "w")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($line = fgetcsv($input, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if ($line[0] == 'Austin'){
                // write only the last bit
                fwrite($output, $line[2] . PHP_EOL);
            } else {
                // by default write the complete line
                fputcsv($output, $line);
            }
        }
        fclose($output);
    }
    fclose($input);
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to do a specific line though, would i be able to do an if statement such as `if($line[0] == 'Austin') { } ` and have only that specific line be affected?

Comment: doesn't seem to work, trying to do that so it goes to a specific line but it keeps deleting all the data instead of the specified line. Do i need to search for the line first and then have it be deleted?

Comment: Sorry, just did anouther minor mod